# Android selector changes color but not size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to use a selector to implement a simple dot indicator for a ViewPager.

The dots are supposed to change color and size when the page is changed, but they only change color, while the size stays the same.

The selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
             <size
               android:height="12dp"
               android:width="12dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/highlight"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
              android:height="6dp"
              android:width="6dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/light_grey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

which is used in a layout

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="@dimen/margin_2x"
  android:src="@drawable/dot_selector">
</ImageView>
```

which is used in onCreate() to show the initial state:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dot_indicator, viewPagerCountDots);
}
viewPagerCountDots.getChildAt(0).setSelected(true);
```

This looks as expected:

[image]

But when I change the selector state when the page is changed like this...

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        viewPagerCountDots.getChildAt(i).setSelected(i == position);
    }
}
```

..it looks like this:

[image]

Invalidating the child or the ViewGroup does not do anything. Any clue what is going wrong here?

**Update**

Calling requestLayout on the child fixes it, as suggested by [Bartek Lipinski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38179716/1009684)

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View dotView = viewPagerCountDots.getChildAt(i);
        dotView.setSelected(i == position);
        dotView.invalidate();
        dotView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `requestLayout()` calls in your `onPageSelected` callback:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        viewPagerCountDots.getChildAt(i).setSelected(i == position);
        viewPagerCountDots.getChildAt(i).requestLayout();
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

alternatively you can change your drawable to have always the same size, so the `setSelected` is enough:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="12dp"
                android:height="12dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/highlight"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="3dp"
                  android:left="3dp"
                  android:right="3dp"
                  android:top="3dp">
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <size
                        android:width="6dp"
                        android:height="6dp"/>
                    <solid android:color="@color/light_grey"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: This works, but there is a slight delay between the color and the size change

Comment: Calling `requestLayout()` is like asking Android to perform a layout pass on a `View`. It doesn't mean it's instant.

Comment: Calling `invalidate()` on the view before calling `requestLayout()` removes the delay.

Comment: @PhilippE. I edited my answer to provide you with another approach you can take

Comment: The second one is probably the better solution as it does not require additional layout passes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
//if you container is LinearLayout ,change to LinearLayout.params 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    //as you wish
    params.width=200;
    params.height=200;
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
           ImageView dotIv= (ImageView)viewPagerCountDots.getChildAt(i);
            dotIv.setImageResource("//normalPic");
            if(i==position){
                dotIv.setImageResource("//selectPic");
                dotIv.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

View sizes are measured once when they are created. Since you set the layout width and height of the ImageView to "wrap_content", non-selected circles will have 6dp size and their size won't change. You can set the layout width and height **"12dp"**.

BTW, I suggest using a library for indicator instead of implementing it. [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) is a good one

Comment: Thanks, but I am actually trying to get away from ViewPagerIndicator, as it is no longer maintained